# how can I specify multiple "init_command"s in Django's setup file

Tags: django, mysql-python

I have the following setup for my connections to a MySQL database in Django.

```
'default': {
    'NAME' : MYSQL_DB_NAME,
    #'ENGINE' : 'mysql',
    'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER' : 'ccurvey',
    'PASSWORD' : MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    'HOST' : MYSQL_HOST,
    'PORT' : '',
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'init_command' : 'set storage_engine=INNODB',
        },
    },
```

so far, so good.

What's the incantation if I want to add another "set" command to my "init_command"

```
        'init_command' : ('set storage_engine=INNODB',
                           'set transaction isolation level read committed'),
```

gives me "connect() argument must be string, not tuple"

```
        'init_command' : ('set storage_engine=INNODB; set transaction isolation level read committed;'),
```

gives me

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me what worked was:

```
{ 'init_command': 'set storage_engine=InnoDB; \
                   set session transaction isolation level read committed'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not is:

```
 "init_command": 'set storage_engine=INNODB,    \
                  set transaction isolation level read committed;', }
```

It is:

```
 "init_command": 'set storage_engine=INNODB,    \
                  SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED', }
```

Comment: @ChrisCurvey - you don't put a comma between the commands, you remove the second SET and put commas between the values. Ie. `SET name1=value1, name2=value2, ...`

Comment: tried this , but getting   `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'TRANSACTION'")`

Comment: `init_command` content is raised as [parameter on connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-options.html): *Statement to execute when connecting to MySQL server. Automatically re-executed if reconnection occurs.* Before include it on your django code you can try it at command level:  `mysql --init-command="SET @somevar:=100"`

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisCurvey's solution is OKay for me.

*ENV: Python3.7.3 + Django2.2.1*

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB, sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" ',
    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
},
```